# how to make a script with the following codes python

Tags: python, automation

Good evening friends,

I have a question about this python code.

```
import requests
resp = requests.post('https://textbelt.com/text', {
  'phone': '5555555555',
  'message': 'Hello world',
  'key': 'textbelt',
})
print(resp.json())
```

I have a list with 100 phone numbers, and I would like to sms them all with a script, one by one.

Maybe there is a smarter/better way to make a code, I don't know really.
How can I change the 'phone': '.....' that takes the numbers one by one and executes it. So instead of copying each number, is there a way to make this automatic ?

Thank you for your time!!

Greetings,

Turkoslocos

Comment: I'd suggest you learn basic Python first, because the solution is really simple. Unfortunately, however, Stack Overflow isn't the place to learn basic Python. Perhaps read this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should store your phone numbers in a [List](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) and then iterate over it.

```
import requests

phone_numbers = [5555555555,6666666666] # all of your phone numbers here

for phone_number in phone_numbers: # for every number, send the sms
    resp = requests.post('https://textbelt.com/text', { 'phone': phone_number, 'message': 'Hello world', 'key': 'textbelt'})
```

Comment: bro, you are fast... I'm going to use it and let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: keep in mind that you need a special key and real phone numbers! lol @turkoslocos

Comment: yes I got a api key!

Comment: Done! it works. Appreciate it very much!

Comment: Great! :) Python is awesome